# .htaccess adicionar excessão de redirecionamento http para https?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Necessito que todo o site seja redirecionado para `https`, porém com uma única página em exceção. 
Esta página está rodando um `iframe` `http` e desejo que a mesma não seja redirecionada para `.https`.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/medidor.html?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meusite.com.br/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: O navegador vai dar mensagem de que o site não é seguro ao abrir um protocolo http (não seguro) dentro de um protocolo seguro (https), e o usuário terá uma tela desagradável e de desconfiança e perderá visitas.

Comment: opa, é um medidor de velocidade do speedtest, ele não roda em https